# Angularjs - How can I get parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters

I have a URL like that:
`http://myproject.com/apartments?location=123&arrival=01&departure=456&rooms=789`

How can I get the value of `location, arrival, departure, rooms` and pass it to my service.

I try to using `$location.search()` but I can not get the values. The result: 
`Object { location=undefined, arrival=undefined, departure=undefined, more...}`

My serivce:

```
angular.module('apartmentService', [])

    .factory('Apartment', function ($http) {
        return {
            get: function (parameters) {

                console.log(parameters);

                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/apartments',
                    params: {location: parameters}
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('apartmentCtrl', [])

    .controller('ApartmentController', function ($scope, $http, $location, Apartment) {
        $scope.loading = true;

        $scope.parameters = {
            location: $location.search().location,
            arrival: $location.search().arrival,
            departure: $location.search().departure,
            rooms: $location.search().rooms
        };

        Apartment.get($scope.parameters).success(function (data) {
            $scope.apartments = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: your URL is a string. So, using ``string.split()``, ``string.indexOf()`` should be enough, no?

Comment: I'm newbie. You can give me a demo? Thank you very much !!!

Comment: There are plenty of samples on the net : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String

Comment: What is the angular version?

Comment: I don't understand, cai you give demo with angularjs?

Comment: Do you use angular 1.1 / 1.2 / 1.3 ? Open `angular.js` file, and read the version number.

Comment: @MuhammadReda Oh sorry. AngularJS v1.3.8

Comment: Kindly paste your routing code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugly unsecure two-liner:

```
paramsObject = {};
window.location.search.replace(/\?/,'').split('&').map(function(o){ paramsObject[o.split('=')[0]]= o.split('=')[1]});
```

paramsObject will be:

```
Object {location: "123", arrival: "01", departure: "456", rooms: "789"}
```

which you can inject directly into your $scope.parameters

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UDK1aBhhPG9OpqUVjDiA)

Answer (score 1):

You're mapping them incorrectly, to retrieve the queryStrings you do:

```
$location.search('arrival')
$location.search('location') 
// etc etc
```

*But* you don't really need to map them... $location.search() **returns an object** (key/value) of all the parameters

```
$scope.parameters = $location.search();

// would return an object { location : '123', arrival : '555' /* etc etc */ }
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I edit to: `$scope.parameters = $location.search();`. The empty object is returned.

Comment: Do you definitely have things at the end of your URL? `whatever.html?location=123&arrival=555` It only returns empty object when there is nothing in the querystring

Comment: If my url like: `http://sleepy.dev:8000/apartments?location=123&arrival=01&departure=456&rooms=789`. It return empty object. But when I add the `#` to my url: `http://sleepy.dev:8000/apartments#?location=123&arrival=01&departure=456&rooms=789`. It will be OK. But when I submit the form through GET method, the `#` is not exits.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the # and ? are both required in order for it to see the params!

Answer (score 1):

Use ui-router. You will love it and it's the proper approach! Trust me!

There is a great example from this link - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 0):

$location.search('queryparamname');

inside the controller 
inject the service $location

see the reference

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
// $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

Comment: use like key value see the documentation

Comment: // given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}

// set foo to 'yipee'
$location.search('foo', 'yipee');
// $location.search() => {foo: 'yipee', baz: 'xoxo'}

Comment: It return the empty object :(

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is because of angular is expecting the data after the url hash.

Meaning that `$location.search` should work if the url look like that: `http://myproject.com/#apartments?location=123&arrival=01&departure=456&rooms=789`.

One thing you can try, is to let the app know its base. Add the following line to your html head tag.

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Joshua, the # and ? are both required for it to work